# Cufon Colour is being over written

Tags: javascript, html, css, cufon

I can't seem to find where in my code, the "Pink" colour on the main navigation menu, once you hover it goes pink and I can't find where it's being over written.

Site: [myfitnessfoods.v9.fw8.co/first](http://myfitnessfoods.v9.fw8.co/first)

I have the script inserted in the head content.

Answer (score 1):

try this maybe it help

```
#mainmenu li a:hover {color:#fff !important}
```

Comment: I did try that, it's in my "green_theme.css" file :(

Comment: you should try then if there's no effect try it from your parent `div` to your `link` **example**: `#header #mainmenu li a:hover`